# Update Property on Firestore Document Based on a timestamp property in same document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore Document which has these 2 properties:

isActive: true
lastDateForSubmission: a timestamp.

I am using the isActive property to enable or disable upload in my React Application. Currently the lastDateForSubmission is just for display.

I dont have any backend servers. I am using plain React and Firebase.

I need to automatically set the isActive property to False after the time in the LastDateForSubmission property.

I have been searching for a solution for a long time that doesnt involve back end servers and i haven't been able to find one.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You will need a backend to trigger some code at the time you want to make the change.  Firestore won't do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore is a database so it cannot execute code by itself. You can however use firestore rules to determine whether writes are or aren't allowed, so whilst this would not change the database `isActive` value, it could still be used to prevent a write after the deadline as specified in your `lastDateForSubmission` variable.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

You can see an example of using firebase rules to access the request time and compare with the target document here: https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-rules-recipes/#time-based-rules-examples, specifically you could compare the `request.time` and `resource.data.lastDateForSubmission` fields.

If you do require changing the variable, then you will have to create a server-side function to do that (e.g. firebase functions), which you can trigger on a cron schedule (e.g. every hour, or depending on the types of time intervals you will be specifying)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. But to run firebase functions i need to setup a node server right?

Comment: They're technically "serverless" which means you don't need to setup the server, firebase will handle that for you. It will spin up a server just to execute your code when required, and then shut down again once complete (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). So you don't need to worry about managing or scaling the server, and there are generous limits within the free tier.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do such things without a server. But fortunately you don't need to maintain a server `Firebase` has firebase cloud functions for that.

You can schedule tasks and update your database.
Look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions